# Features of kableExtra do not work (Rmarkdown) anymore after installation of Tex package for MacOs Mojave

Tags: macos, latex, r-markdown, kableextra

I have been trying to generate and design a table in `rMarkdown` using `kableExtra` package. I am aiming at a Word knit output of the document. Therefore I installed `LaTexiT` package as suggested by Rmd as a necessity to knit to Word and PDF.

Before the latex installation, the table I was making came exactly as I wished by using `kableExtra` and the features `kable_styling()`, `pac_rows()+row_spec()`, `add_header_above()`. I got what I wanted with nice columns grouping and colouring of headers.

Right after I installed `LaTexiT` not even the html would produce - what it was producing just before. I am in the process of writing a paper and I need to be able to knit in word or PDF.

My df is is

```
data.frame':    33 obs. of  9 variables:


 $ TAXON                : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...


 $ Among.all.three.sites: Factor w/ 11 levels "Amigos species #1461",..: 7 10 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...


 $ Among.two.sites      : Factor w/ 13 levels "Chulos species #1992",..: 2 4 7 10 13 NA NA NA NA NA ...


 $ Site_A         : Factor w/ 18 levels "Figaro species #1784",..: 10 11 12 13 16 18 NA NA NA NA ...


 $ Site_B...5        : Factor w/ 21 levels "Siamese species",..: 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 13 16 ...


 $ Site_C       : Factor w/ 22 levels "Joyful species #1990",..: 5 21 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...


 $ Site_A         : Factor w/ 9 levels "Austroungarian species",..: 8 9 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...


 $ Site_B       : Factor w/ 22 levels "Whatever species",..: 1 19 3 9 15 16 17 18 21 NA ...


 $ Site_C       : Factor w/ 18 levels "Love you species #1990",..: 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 12 13 ...
```

So I basically need to group column 2 and 3 under one header, 4, 5 and 6 under another and 7, 8 and 9 under another again.

Also under the header line, I need to add an extra grouping for the rows from 1-13, another one from 14-28 and another one from 29-33.

This is the code I have been using in Rmarkdown and which did work before:

```
Table_1 <- read.table("Table.txt", header=T)
devtools::install_github("haozhu233/kableExtra")
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
options(knitr.table.format = "latex")
 options(knitr.kable.NA = '')#I have empty cells

kable(Table_1[1:33, 1:9], format="latex", caption = "Table 1. Good stuff",col.names=c("Taxon","Among all three sites", "Among two sites", "Site_A","Site_B", "Site_C", "Site_A", "Site_B","Site_C" )) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_option="striped", full_width = TRUE) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "First Header" = 2, "Second header" = 3, "third header"=3)) %>%
  pack_rows("Taxon1", 1, 13,label_row_css = "background-color: #99999C; color: #fff;") %>%
   row_spec(1:13, italic = T)%>%
  pack_rows("Taxon2", 14, 28,label_row_css = "background-color: #99999C; color: #fff;")%>%
    row_spec(14:28, italic = T)%>%
  pack_rows("Taxon3", 29, 33,label_row_css = "background-color: #99999C; color: #fff;")%>%
    row_spec(29:33, italic = T)


knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE,
    message = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE)
```

The code I used initially did everything perfectly but after the installation of latex app on my MacOS it does not responding any more.

Can anyone help me in finding out what happened? Anything I change in the code does not change the knit result now, independent from Word or PDF or html... Do I need to uninstall `LatexiT`?

Thank you all for helping, it is driving me a bit crazy...

As example I am uploading a image of a table made in excel now, but which initially I managed to achieve with `Kablextra`

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a document that you think should work, but which no longer works for you?  What you've posted might allow us to construct one, but it's almost certainly not the same as yours, so it would be a lot quicker if you did it.  Don't worry about including real data, just build `Table_1` out of fake data.

Comment: user2554330 thank you for willing to help. I added a link to the image of what I would like to achieve. Thanks a lot for wanting to help. Meanwhile I dropped the idea to achieve such design and I am going with a much simpler design using packages magrittr and flextable - it seems fairly easier although I am struggling with the italic

Comment: Are you sure you want latexit and not rather a real latex distribution like texlive or mactex?

Comment: Do you get any .log file or error messages?